# Remove empty list from multidimensional list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, elementtree

I am working with Elemtree to extract text and attributes from an XML document. 
I successfully am able to extract the data that I need from the file and populate a multidimensional list. My problem is that I have a number of empty lists trailing the populated lists.

Here is the snippet:

```
res_hq_schema = []

for folder in root.iter('folder'):
    res_hq_schema.append([])
    res_hq_schema[0].append(folder.text)


for name in root.iter('name'):
    res_hq_schema.append([])
    res_hq_schema[1].append(name.text)

for is_up in root.iter('is_up'):
    res_hq_schema.append([])
    res_hq_schema[2].append(is_up.text)

for snmp_uptime in root.iter('snmp_uptime'):
    res_hq_schema.append([])
    res_hq_schema[3].append(snmp_uptime.text)


print(res_hq_schema)
```

And here is the output:

```
[['RES-HQ-WIRELESS', 'RES-HQ-WIRELESS', 'RES-HQ-WIRELESS', 'RES-HQ-WIRELESS', 'RES-HQ-WIRELESS', 'RES-HQ-WIRELESS', 'RES-HQ-WIRELESS', 'RES-HQ-WIRELESS'],
['RES-HQ-AP-C5:63:44', 'RES-HQ-AP-C5:63:00', 'RES-HQ-AP-C5:62:F2', 'RES-HQ-AP-C5:63:1C', 'RES-HQ-AP-C5:63:34', 'RES-HQ-AP-C5:62:F6', 'RES-HQ-AP-C5:63:28', 'RES-HQ-MD01'],
['true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true'],
['1320681', '1332436', '1319971', '1319965', '1332442', '1319958', '1320199', '38365'],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[]]
```

Please let me know if any further information is required

Comment: This seems like a good place for a list comprehension. Something like `res_hq_schema = [i for i in res_hq_schema if i]` should work.

Comment: Give Pythons filter function a try: ```res_hq_filtered = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0))``` actually I prefer list comprehensions like in Axe319 comment, but it's an alternative to it.